# Как реализовать обтекание одного блока другим блоком с помощью Bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Суть такая что этот блок должен стоять в этом месте.

Как это возможно сделать с помощью Bootstrap?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3 ">
                <div class="photos2"></div>
            </div>              
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Вам должно помочь применение простого `.col-md-4 {float: right;}`, ну, либо я чего-то не понимаю.

Comment: при данном html – никак

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Будет интереснее менять количество столбцов - от двух на самом узком экране до шести на самом широком. Для этого заменим класс `col-md-4` на `col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2`.

Все ячейки разместим в одной строке. Зелёный блок поставим первым.

**Вариант 1**. Всем ячейкам добавляем класс `pull-right`.

Недостаток - если последняя не заполнена целиком, то ячейки прижмутся вправо и слева останется пустое пространство.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.photos {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.photos-2 {
  background-color: #093;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos-2"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos"></div></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

---

**Вариант 2**. Добавляем `pull-right` только первой зелёной ячейке и расставляем `clearfix`. Если серые блоки одинаковой высоты, то для каждой ширины экрана нужен только один `clearfix`.

Недостаток: чтобы рассчитать разметку, надо знать, насколько зелёный блок  выше серых.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

.photos {
  background-color: #ccc;
  height: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.photos-2 {
  background-color: #093;
  height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2 pull-right"><div class="photos-2"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-xs-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2"><div class="photos"></div></div>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы не правильно строете размету, попробуйте так:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <!-- первая строка закончена -->
            <div class="clearfix visible-block"></div>

            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <!-- вторая строка закончена -->
            <div class="clearfix visible-block"></div>

            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <div class="col-md-3"><div class="photos"></div></div>
            <!-- третья строка закончена -->
            <div class="clearfix visible-block"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Перед последними 4-мя div элементами для сброса строки:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-block"></div>
```

И ознакомитесь на будущее с классом `.clearfix` или же используйте `.row`
для каждой вашей строки, а элементу добавьте класс `.pull-right`.